# Вызов метода из созданного класса с помощью Javassist

Tags: java

Значит, мучаюсь я с Javassist. Помаленьку начинаю понимать, что и к чему.

Вот сейчас застрял и что-то никак не могу найти, как вызвать метод из существующего (созданного) класса с помощью Javassist.

```
import javassist.CannotCompileException;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import javassist.CtNewMethod;
import javassist.NotFoundException;

public class JavassistCode {
    private ClassPool pool;
    private CtClass ctClass;
    private CtMethod javassitMethod;
    private String expression = "x*x+x/2";
    private String method ="public double eval(double x){return{"+ expression +"};}";
    private MyFrame myframe;

    public JavassistCode(MyFrame myFrame) throws CannotCompileException, NotFoundException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        this.myframe=myFrame;

        pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        ctClass = pool.makeClass("javassistClass");

        javassitMethod = CtNewMethod.make(method, ctClass);
        ctClass.addMethod(javassitMethod);

        Class clazz = ctClass.toClass();

    }

}
```

Вот похожая [статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/69728/), но я что-то не могу догнать, как там запускается метод и выдает результат.. :(

Подскажите, что не так? Спасибо!

И еще вопросик, читаю по данной теме, одни пишут одно, а другие показывают совершенно другие примеры.

**Мне нужно создать класс с помощью Javassist, потом связать его с другими объектами приложения...**

Как показывает офф. мануал - это возможно, а в одной статье читал, что это невозможно. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас на руках есть объект, то найти его методы и запустить можно с помощью [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html). Пример запуска метода через рефлексию приведен [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал. :)